# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Tags: html, datatable

I got this error in datatable. I have included all header files corrrectly but don't know why this error occurs.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of
>   undefined TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

I tried some solutions like no empty rows, equal number of headings and columns etc. but nothing worked here. Please help.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover datatable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Target</th>
               <th>Goal</th>
               <th>Target Status</th> 
               <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Demo Target</td>
               <td>Some Goal</td>
               <td>Some Status</td>
               <td>Some Date</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js code-

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
       autoWidth: false,
       dom: '<"datatable-header"fBl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
       language: {
           search: '<span>Filter:</span> _INPUT_', 
           searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
           lengthMenu: '<span>Show:</span> _MENU_',
           paginate: { 'first': 'First', 'last': 'Last', 'next': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;', 'previous': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;' }
       }
   });

   var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
       buttons: {            
           buttons: [
               {
                   extend: 'copyHtml5',
                   className: 'btn btn-light',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: [ 0, ":visible" ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'excelHtml5',
                   className: 'btn btn-light',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: [ 0, ":visible" ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                   className: 'btn btn-light',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: [ 0, ":visible" ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'colvis',
                   text: '<i class="icon-three-bars"></i>',
                   className: 'btn bg-blue btn-icon dropdown-toggle'
               }
           ]
       },
       "aaSorting": []
   });
```

Comment: In order for us to be able to assist you better, we also need to see the initialization of the datatable in your js code.

Comment: @Alex initialization of datatable has been updated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with your code, it works just fine on my end. I would check your html for duplicates i.e. using `.datatable` class in another spot and would use an id to initiate it.